# php mysql insert from select fires error

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert

I try to make an insert in PHP from a SELECT like seen in this SQL Fiddle [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9e208/4).

My code:

```
$sql2 .= "INSERT INTO $tableBackup (Fahrer, Datum, Baustelle, Arbeitsbeginn, Arbeitsende, Projektbeginn, Projektende, Arbeitszeit, Projektzeit, Pausenzeit, Reine AZ, Sonntag, Feiertag, Urlaub, Krank, Stundensatz, Auslöse, Gesamt)";
        $sql2 .= "SELECT t.*,";
        $sql2 .= "sum(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(Arbeitsbeginn, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s'), STR_TO_DATE(Arbeitsende, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s')))) AS ARBEITSZEIT, sum(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(Projektbeginn, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s'), STR_TO_DATE(Projektende, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s')))) AS Projektzeit";
        $sql2 .= "FROM (SELECT DriverName AS Fahrer, Datum,Baustelle,Arbeitsbeginn,Arbeitsende,Projektbeginn,Projektende";
        $sql2 .= "FROM (SELECT DRIVERNAME,left(`datetime`, 10) as Datum,,GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'PB', AREA, NULL)) AS 'Baustelle',GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'Arbeitsbeginn', DATETIME, NULL)) AS 'Arbeitsbeginn',GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'Arbeitsende', DATETIME, NULL)) AS 'Arbeitsende',GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'PB', DATETIME, NULL)) AS 'Projektbeginn',GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'PE', DATETIME, NULL)) AS 'Projektende'";
        $sql2 .= "FROM geoImportRoot GROUP BY DRIVERNAME) A CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 2) n) t";
        $sql2 .= "GROUP BY Fahrer, Datum;";
        $this->DB->Execute($sql2);
```

And the structure of the new table:

```
`geoEdit` (
`ID` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Fahrer` text NOT NULL,
`Datum` text NOT NULL,
`Baustelle` text NOT NULL,
`Arbeitsbeginn` text NOT NULL,
`Arbeitsende` text NOT NULL,
`Projektbeginn` text NOT NULL,
`Projektende` text NOT NULL,
`Arbeitszeit` text NOT NULL,
`Projektzeit` text NOT NULL,
`Pausenzeit` smallint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`Reine AZ` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`Sonntag` text,
`Feiertag` text,
`Urlaub` text,
`Krank` text,
`Stundensatz` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
`Auslöse` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`Gesamt` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

It does not work. Before firing this script I do an INSERT with data into the root table geoImportRoot.

Comment: Define **It does not work.** and btw you are using `INSERT` but not inserting any `VALUES`

Comment: @SebastianRush you do know you can have multiple lines in an sql statement, there's no need to concatenate/uglify your query. also perhaps fix `$sql2 .= "INSERT` to `$sql2 = "INSERT`

Comment: Please supply error message. Also when concatening strings make sure to include white space where needed, for example you are missing whitespace between projektende and the FROM on the next line.

Answer (score 2):

Here space creates the problem in your query, use backtick around it

```
 Pausenzeit, Reine AZ, Sonntag,
                  ^

 Pausenzeit, `Reine AZ`, Sonntag,
```

Comment: +1 Is there any reason for problem due to space ? I think he should use double quotes as back ticks are used for table and column names.

Comment: @Vivek space is used for creating alias. And if anyone creating column_name with space then he should use backtick to create it as single column name. We can only use backtick for table_name and column_name in `mysql`, if we use `double quote` or `single quote` the query will give error.

Comment: Ohh.. yes (Pausenzeit, Reine AZ, Sonntag,) these are column names i thought that these are data values.  :)